# NSOperationQueue doesn't stop when [operation cancelAllOperations] is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I created this queue in my iOS app, and I'd like to stop it:

In my .h file:

```
NSOperationQueue *uhm;
```

In my .m file:
in viewDidLoad: `NSOperationQueue *uhm = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];`

in my method:

```
[uhm addOperation:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
        … //Here I do operations that retrive data from my server
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }
    }]];
```

but when I call `[uhm cancelAllOperations]` it just set the boolean value `isCancelled` on YES, but doesn't stop the execution of queue!
Please help me!

Comment: thats how it works. you gotta program your operations to check isCancelled

Answer (score 4):

Cancelling an operation doesn't actually stop any executing operation.

It just stops new ones from being started.

You have to stop any current operations manually in the operation itself.

For instance, if you have code that collects downloaded data then before you concatenate the data check if the operation is cancelled.

If the operation is cancelled then end the operation.

[image]

There are many ways to do this. It depends on what is inside your operation.

Comment: I thought there, but how can I do it?

Comment: @Pinturikkio it entirely depends on how you have coded the operation code. Ah... you have done it as "addOperationWithBlock" you can't really do much with them. I'd recommend subclassing `NSOperation` and doing it that way.

Comment: In my block of operations I simply doing the operations that I wrote, and where I put the lines of comments I do for example myString = @"..."; . My goal is to recall the same method when it is in execution

Comment: Yeah, you should really create a sub class of NSOperation and have your download code there. Then whenever you get an update you can check the `isCancelled` state and stop it running if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned that you are calling the cancelAllOperations from another method,, and the object you allocated is not in your **.h** so you are calling another object not the same "hum" that you initialised.

so try to declare the NSOperationQueue *uhm; in your .h so it will be global then you can call [uhm cancelAllOperations]; from any method in .m you want.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, this is an example, my NSOperationQueue is defined in .h .